# Is there a way to list all DOM changes made via Chrome Developer Tools?

Tags: google-chrome

A common development practice is to make changes to CSS and HTML via Chrome Developer Tools > Elements to get immediate feedback on possible UI tweaks. When doing this I keep a pad of paper to note my changes as I go. It would be much more convenient if there were some way to access a list of changes that Chrome is aware of, or a diff, etc. Does such a thing exist?

This idea came from doing work away from my desk and not having a pen handy. I tried taking notes in a text file and it was very difficult to "flow".

Note:
[This seems pretty promising](https://superuser.com/a/451850/3376), but does not work for me since I am making my changes to content served via `http://` and not `file://`

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/setup/setup-workflow to map `http` to the filesystem

Comment: The problem is that what is served does not map to anything on my filesystem.